# from a series of datetimes, how to downsample and select less number of dates and put them in the x labels and xticks?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, xvalue

i am making a plot on which the x axis represents dates and the y axis represents total covid cases. the problem is that due to a large dataset, there are many dates on the x axis and when i am ploting that i am getting a plot on which the xtick values are overlapped and i can not clearly see the covid cases at a particular date. so i want to make a clear graph. how can i do that? or you can also suggest me any better idea to make the graph more readable.
i am giving my code and plot below. Thanks. [image: my plot]

Comment: What's the issue? You can't see the dates on the x axis because you are plotting a curve with a lot of points. If you wanted to see them separately, plot an histogram (but it will be a total mess on the axis if you have too many points)

Comment: yes. thats why i want to built an efficient way by which i can overcome this problem.

Comment: Well there's no answer to your question (with matplotlib). Though, you could :
* slice your 'x' axis in multiple subaxis and then plot using 'scatter'
* only take the specific dates you want to plot to highlight them

Answer (score 1):

- ensure your dates are dates not strings
- Use [matplotlib date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html)
- I've used data from UK as you did not provide sample

```
x = countries["date"]
y = countries["total_cases"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]